# JSON object accessor returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm working with some JSON through jQuery, and thought I was doing it correctly, but I keep getting undefined.

If my JSON is organized like so:

```
{ "item1" : "answer",
  "name" : "something",
  "title" : "your title",
  "favorites" : [ { 
      "color" : "blue",
      "season" : "winter",
      "sport" : "baseball"
      },
      { ... more favorite objects ... }]
}
```

Then I call it with

```
$.getJSON(urlOfMyJSON, null, function(json){
    $("p").append(json.item1); // returns 'answer'
    $("h3").append(json.favorites); // returns undefined
    $("h4").append(json.favorites[0].color); // thought this should work; throws an error because undefined has no "color".
});
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction? I know what I want to do, I'm just not quite sure what I'm missing.

Thank you!

Comment: throw json into console.log and see what comes out.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the json references you have so the issue must either be with the actual JSON you're seeing or something related to your HTML (which you don't show).  I'm also not seeing that you can call append with an array of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your JSON or the code accessing the properties of the resulting deserialized object. [Live example.](http://jsbin.com/omewiy) However, this line:

```
$("h3").append(json.favorites);
```

Doesn't make much sense. You're asking jQuery to take this array:

```
[
    { 
        "color" : "blue",
        "season" : "winter",
        "sport" : "baseball"
    }
]
```

...and append it to all of the `h3` elements on your page. jQuery will use `toString` on that, as it's not a DOM element or jQuery instance, and the `toString` will presumably come back `[object Object]` or similar.

The next line, `$("h4").append(json.favorites[0].color);`, should work fine though, as the live link above demonstrates. Provided there are `h4` elements on the page for it to update!

Answer (score 1):

do that to see the problem:

```
$.getJSON(urlOfMyJSON, null, function(json){
   alert(json.toSource());
});
```